# Connect to Nginx Pod in Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

I have deployed an nginx pod using the [bitnami nginx helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/nginx). I've played around with the port configs in an attempt to allow a connection from another pod inside the same namespace but haven't had any success.

Current override:

```yaml
global:
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: dockercredentials

image:
  registry: my-private-registry.com
  repository: nginx/nginx
  tag: 1.23
  debug: true

service:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    # Configures the LB to use this subnet in azure to get an IP
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "my-azure-subnet"

serverBlock: |-
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;
    listen 8443;
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8; # may or may not be necessary.
        proxy_pass https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
  }


extraEnvVars:
  - name: http_proxy
    value: http://my.proxy:8000
  - name: https_proxy
    value: http://my.proxy:8000

containerSecurityContext:
  enabled: true
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  runAsNonRoot: false
  runAsUser: 0
# Enable https port
containerPorts:
  https: 8443

livenessProbe:
  enabled: false
readinessProbe:
  enabled: false
```

The pod and corresponding service are deployed:

```
k describe service/nginx-load-balancer

....
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  31226/TCP
Endpoints:                10.245.116.86:8080
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               https/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31509/TCP
Endpoints:                10.245.116.86:8443
....
```

```
 k describe deployment.apps/nginx-load-balancer

....
  Containers:
   nginx:
    Image:       my-private-registry.com/nginx/nginx:1.23
    Ports:       8080/TCP, 8443/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Environment:
      BITNAMI_DEBUG:            true
      NGINX_HTTP_PORT_NUMBER:   8080
      NGINX_HTTPS_PORT_NUMBER:  8443
      http_proxy:               http://my.proxy:8000
      https_proxy:              http://my.proxy:8000
....
```

When I attempt to establish a connection from another pod on 80 or 443 I receive a connection refused. On 8443 or 8080 the connection hangs. Curling yields the same behavior.

```
# telnet 10.245.116.152 443
Trying 10.245.116.152...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
# telnet 10.245.116.152 80
Trying 10.245.116.152...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
# telnet 10.245.116.152 8080
Trying 10.245.116.152...
^C
# telnet 10.245.116.152 8443
Trying 10.245.116.152...
^C
#
```

From my understanding of the `Service Port` and then the `Target Port` shouldn't traffic be accepted on 443 or 80 and forwarded to 8443 and 8080 respectively? My ultimate goal is to route traffic to this specific nginx pod and have it use the `proxy_pass` setting in the `nginx.conf`/`serverBlock` section to redirect the traffic to `example.com`. Any ideas here?

I also attempted to curl the service using `service` name, `service-namespace` and also the IP of the load balancer.

```
# curl -v nginx-load-balancer
*   Trying 172.20.41.169:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.20.41.169 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to nginx-load-balancer port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to nginx-load-balancer port 80: Connection refused
# curl -v nginx-load-balancer.my-ns
*   Trying 172.20.41.169:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 172.20.41.169 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to nginx-load-balancer.my-ns port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to nginx-load-balancer.my-ns port 80: Connection refused
# curl -v 10.245.116.152
*   Trying 10.245.116.152:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 10.245.116.152 port 80 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 10.245.116.152 port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.245.116.152 port 80: Connection refused
```

Comment: Unless your container is running a telnet server (very unlikely in this millennium) you probably want to use an HTTP client like `curl`, and you should use the service name `nginx-load-balancer` as a host name.  I think you're actually connecting to the Pod (hence the port mismatch), and the server is waiting for you to send a plain-text request like `GET / HTTP/1.1` -- for you to type the HTTP protocol into the `telnet` client.

Comment: Hey @DavidMaze thanks for the reply. I actually tried with curl as well and attempted using the service name, service name - namespace and also the IP of the load balancer and none seemed to work. I've edited the original post showing the curl requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection issued was a result of a bad nginx image for the bitnami chart. After switching to the latest bitnami nginx image, connections were seen. It hasn't solved my issue with using nginx as a forward/transparent proxy but that seems more to do with the limitations of nginx.